# How to validate two arguments on nginx after do a captcha validation

Tags: redirect, nginx, conditional-statements

I want to redirect on NGINX certain ID on the URL to a ReCaptcha validation, when is validated, reCaptcha append a token.

So if this ID and this Token are in the query there is when NGINX must let it pass like the others IDs.

I stuck here:

```
if ( $args ~ "id=theId" ) {
    set $validated = 0;
    return 301 http://myvalidation.example.com/run.html$uri$args;
}
```

Comment: Nginx is a web server, it's not really designed to handle client authentication like this. I would recommend you look at the Nginx [auth_request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) and [auth_basic](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) modules as more robust methods for managing client access which include delegating the auth process to a dedicated (ie more suitable) server

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($arg_id = STRING_VALUE) {
    return 301 http://myvalidation.example.com/run.html$uri$args;
}
```